# Is it possible to get program start and end addresses using GetSystemInfo() in C?

Tags: c, winapi, memory

I'm currently learning windows.h lib. According to docs, it is possible to know the minimum and maximum program addresses by means of `lpMinimumApplicationAddress` and `lpMaximumApplicationAddress` fields of `SYSTEM_INFO` structure, `GetSystemInfo()` function. However, I'm wondering: is it possible to get program start and end address, using `GetSystemInfo()`? If possible, how?
Thank you for advance.

Comment: No, with `GetSystemInfo()` you can't. Why does it have to be that function? Can't you use [`GetModuleInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmoduleinformation)?

Comment: What does *"program start address"* and *"program end address"* mean to you?

Comment: Do *"program start address"* and *"program end address"* mean [virtual address space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#memory-and-address-space-limits)?

Comment: ...or does it mean `[EntryPoint, EntryPoint + SizeOfImage)`  from [`MODULEINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/ns-psapi-moduleinfo)?

Comment: Why is it important to you that you just use GetSystemInfo() to get the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the actual address that program terminates on (or whether it terminates at all), no. That is just a variation on the famous halting problem. And that has been proven to not have a general solution.

Minimum and maximum address are just what memory has been assigned to a process, but there could be many places in it that the program would terminate at, depending on the exact run parameters. And it might not even reach any of them.